# Who can sniff my packets?

Tags: packet, sniffing

If I make a call to some server who can sniff my packets?

Obviously anyone who is on my network can sniff, but on the server side also?

My call will make several hops to the destination server, can they sniff my packets at these intermediate hops also?

Comment: short answer is 'yes' to all of the above

Comment: Maybe you need to explain what you mean by 'sniffing'?

Comment: @Schroeder: Wireshark for example @Schroeder/KanekiDev: Ok, I understand

Comment: Yes, wireshark is the most known sniffer.
It can be used anywhere in the network (your network, server network, intermediate hops network) that the packet goes through, to sniff the data.

It does NOT mean that your data is in risk, it depends on the security measures you're using (for example if web-browsing, using https; or using ssl)

Answer (score 2):

AS @Schroeder said: YES.

Every data packet can be sniffed anywhere over any network the packet goes through.

Comment: But whether or not that packet contains sensitive information is questionable. Might have your SSN in cleartext, might be garbled ciphertext.

Comment: Yep that's right too.
Also it is questionable if the sniffed information may mean a leakage. You can sniffer encrypted packets, but you won't get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine it as a car moving from point A to point B. The sniffing process might be a CCTV filming this car. Any intersection is a hop.

Can this car be spotted at any intersection by a CCTV?

**YES**

If the communication is encrypted, the CCTV can spot the car but it cannot see what it is inside the car.

Answer (score 0):

For either clientside LAN, in transit on WAN, or serverside LAN:

Packets can be sniffed easily. 
Firing up something like Wireshark (tcpdump) will let you see the source and destination IP of the packet (always in cleartext), and the contents (either in cleartext or encrypted).

Through LAN network manipulation you can modify network traffic to inject code or disable encryption with for example software like [Nighthawk](https://github.com/klemenb/nighthawk) (windows) or [MITMProxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy).

manipulating traffic in transit on WAN will be harder but the resources of the likely threat there are also much more vast

for example [codename QUANTUMINSERT](https://blog.fox-it.com/2015/04/20/deep-dive-into-quantum-insert/):

> The documents leaked by former National Security Agency (NSA)
>   contractor Edward Snowden mention dozens of hard- and software attacks
>   available to the NSA to gain and maintain access to target networks.